# Why peel tomatoes when making salsa?

Tags: tomatoes

I'm making salsa. Do I really need to peel the tomatoes? I've canned salsa and stewed tomatoes for years. Peeling is such a messy process. If I chop the tomatoes in my food processor do I really need to peel them?

Also my salsa is quite runny. Is that why I should core and seed them? Just what is the core?

Comment: Welcome! We have a previous question that I think pretty much answers the "why peel?" question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7519/why-peel-tomatoes

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that it is a personal preference, but many people are very off-put by the texture of the skins.  Probably more in a smoother salsa than in a chunkier one.  Also, the skins can often be bitter and peeling eliminates that.